# EWS-Managed-Api SearchFilter worked with Exchange-Server-2010 but not working against Exchange-server-2013

Tags: c#, ews-managed-api, exchange-server-2013

We upgraded our Exchange server from 2010 to 2013. We have an application that searches for emails sent to a specific account. This is the search filter

```
    SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And,
        new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false),
        new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.HasAttachments, true),
        new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients,
            "admin@someaccount.com", 
            ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, 
            ComparisonMode.IgnoreCase)
    );
```

This worked against 2010 but returns nothing for 2013 and I think that it is the 
`SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring` that is failing.

Has this functionality changed between the two versions of Exchange?

Comment: Looks like this issue still exist in EWS API 2.2. Have you found any workaround?

Comment: @02Anant: yes I used a query string: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn579420%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx